# How to pass dynamic chat id in xmpp server in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, xmpp

I want to make chat system using xmpp and node js
For this i read socket and make connection and communicate with server.
This is working fine.
But now i have to pass chat id to xmpp server should be different for each user 
How can be done this in node

This is my app.js node server file

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('keys/private.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('keys/certificate.pem')
  };
  var app = require('https').createServer(options, handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
 function handler(res) {
      res.send('working');
  }
  var xmpp = require('node-xmpp');
 var connection = new xmpp.Client({
   jid: '585bde79ba5d097423ad0d78@testing.twodegrees.io',
   password: '585bde79ba5d097423ad0d78',
  });
```

I want to set dynamic jid and password
How this can be done 
I am using angularjs+socket and node js

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `uuid` module from npm

Comment: Please see the documentation for `uuid` the usage is very basic (two lines of code at most) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid